# Autocomplete for passwords in IE WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

We are hosting the IE .NET WebBrowser control in our desktop app and navigate to our website that requires authentication. In standalone IE, the user is asked if they want IE to save the password, but they don't get asked in the WebBrowser control.

Does anybody know if this feature can be turned on for the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to turn this on for WebBrowser, but if you require the functionality then you're probably best off using IE itself (or, preferably, a better browser!).

If you really want that feature, you could provide an API on your server that allows automated logins from your program, then implement the "save password" facility in your client app code.